# Django: Shorten code in template and avoid duplicates

Tags: django

I have the following written in my template. Is it possible to shorten that code as `request.resolver_match.namespaces` is currently twice in it?

```
{% if 'admin' not in request.resolver_match.namespaces and 'website' not in request.resolver_match.namespaces %}
```

Comment: It could be something like that: `{% if ('admin' and 'website') not in request.resolver_match.namespaces %}
`

Comment: Are you sure that this will work correctly? `('admin' and 'website')` evaluates first and you'll get `'website'` as a result. And then we check only `'website'` on our namespaces list. Try this example: `if ('admin' and 'website') not in ('admin', 'second', 'third'): print("Hello")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- use a `{% with %}` block

  ```
   {% with namespaces=request.resolver_match.namespaces %}
       {% if 'admin' not in namespaces and 'website' not in namespaces %}
       ...
       {% endif %}
   {% endwith %}
  ```
- use a context processor

  ```
  def add_namespace(request):
      return {'namespaces': request.resolver_match.namespaces}

  {% if 'admin' not in namespaces and 'website' not in namespaces %}
  ```

  or:

  ```
  def check_namespace(request):
      invalid_namespaces = ['admin', 'website']
      namespaces_valid = all(
          s not in request.resolver_match.namespaces
          for s in invalid_namespaces
      )
      return {'namespaces_valid': namespaces_valid}
  ```

  You have to add the path to the callable to `context_processors` list in your `TEMPLATES` setting.
- create a custom template filter that does the check:

  ```
  # your_app/templatetags/namespaces.py
  @register.filter
  def namespaces_valid(value):
      invalid_namespaces = ['admin', 'website']
      return all(
          s not in request.resolver_match.namespaces
          for s in invalid_namespaces
      )

  {% load namespaces %}
  {% if request.resolver_match.namespaces|namespaces_valid %}
  ```

However, I would take a step back and check if it is a good idea to tie the templates to URLs as you are trying to do. My guess is you want to do some app-specific stuff in a global base template. Maybe you can achieve that with an intermediate base template and the use of a `{% block %}`:

```
 # base.html, which currently contains your {% if ... %}
 {% block not_admin_or_website %}
 {% endblock %}

 # base_not_admin_or_website.html
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block not_admin_or_website %}
     ... # whatever is in your if right now
 {% endblock %}
```